# Does all running docker containers have a separate process ID

Tags: process, containers, docker, pid

Does all the running docker containers have a separate process id. If yes, how can one get that. Also, what will happen if we kill that process?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, every docker container will have a different PID on your host machine.

You can get a docker containers PID by doing:

```
docker inspect --format '{{ .State.Pid }}' CONTAINER_ID
```

If you kill the process on your host, your docker container will die.

Comment: Thanks Chris!

Do you have an idea on their relationship with the docker daemon process?

Comment: docker daemon process will be a parent of a process in container when you will look at processes on host:
$ docker top romantic_archimedes
UID                 PID                 PPID                C                   STIME               TTY                 TIME                CMD  
root                19742               2470                0                   18:28               pts/4               00:00:00            bash  
    $ ps -p 2470  
      PID TTY          TIME CMD  
     2470 ?        00:00:07 docker  

Inside of container you first process will have pid 1